# Refresh the Database Table

Tags: sql

I have a table, which is fill of duplicate rows. I need to refresh the table by removing all the duplicate rows. I can do it with writing procedure. it there any fastest way for this?

Comment: Can you give more details like the columns of your table

Comment: Your question makes no sense. Have you at least searched for _"remove duplicates sql"_?

Comment: What RDBMS do you use (MS SQL Server, MySql, Oracle, etc). I'm sure that for different servers there might be different solutions.

Comment: try it with removing procedure!

Comment: Doing a quick search on google on [remove duplicate sql](http://www.google.com/search?q=remove+duplicate+sql) will help a lot. Other than that, try to follow the premises on [how to ask a question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask). Also tag your question adequately to the RDBMS you are using, add your table structures and some code you have tried.

Comment: You can find the answer here http://bit.ly/PYe217

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELETE MyTable 
FROM MyTable
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
   SELECT MIN(RowId) as RowId, Col1, Col2, Col3 
   FROM MyTable 
   GROUP BY Col1, Col2, Col3
) as KeepRows ON
   MyTable.RowId = KeepRows.RowId
WHERE
   KeepRows.RowId IS NULL
```